# Does webmatrix Database class uses ADO.Net internally?

Tags: ado.net, webmatrix

Is Database class just a wrapper for ADO.NET which makes use of db simpler ? What's its limits ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - the Database Helper is a wrapper around ADO.NET. It is designed to minimize the code that a beginner needs to get started with querying databases, similar to how its done in PHP. Its limits depend on your point of view. As someone who is just starting to learn web development and databases, you might think that the helper is a stroke of genius. As a professional developer, you might not like the fact that it returns dynamic types or that it doesn't prevent people dynamically constructing their SQL and potentially opening up their application to SQL injection attacks.